# Why does getActiveCell stop working when I have multiple sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am not actually sure whether it is `getActiveCell` or something else that is failing, but this is the code I'm having trouble with:

```
var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var program2define = dataSheet.getActiveCell();
var tempContents = program2define.getDisplayValue();
```

When I have just one sheet, this gets the string in the active cell, no problems. When I add another sheet, suddenly it gets an empty string. I've checked and double checked, I've tried using getSheetByName instead of getActiveSheet - same problem. I've tried it in a test sheet with only one cell filled - same problem as soon as I add another sheet.

When I searched, I [found this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/QlGpE7_ZIFk;context-place=forum/docs) but the problem is the same (empty String) even if I make sure every sheet in the spreadsheet has an active cell that is filled.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this. When I run your code on my spreadsheet and log the value of tempContents, it logs whatever is in the active cell. One difference between Google Sheets and Excel is that you can only have one sheet selected at a time. This means that if you are looking at a different (blank) spreadsheet, your code will return that, not whatever you have selected on another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

[getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet) gets the active sheet in a spreadsheet and you can only have 1 active sheet at a time, even an active cell. So it doesn't make sense that you'd apply it in multiple sheets.